# How to update json data stored in a text field in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table `services` which has a column named `properties` whose type is `text`.

There are `json` data stored in `properties` column.

I can query `json` data with `psql` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM services WHERE properties::json->>'url' = 'www.example.com';
```

But I cannot update the `json` data with the following query:

```
UPDATE 
   services SET properties::json->>'url' = 'www.mydomain.com' 
WHERE 
   properties::json->>'url' = 'www.example.com';
```

The `UPDATE` command above generates the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"
LINE 1: UPDATE services SET properties::json->>'url' = 'www.....
```

How can I update the `url` field inside the `properties` column?

What's wrong with my `UPDATE` command?

Comment: Can you share sample data from json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your `JSON` so i am use my sample.

You can use `REPLACE` function to `REPLACE` string `example` with `domain` and after that you cast to `JSON` but it would be good you change your `properties` type column `text` to `json`.

*REPLACE Definition*:

> Replace all occurrences in string of substring from with substring to

```
update services
set properties = replace(properties,'example','domain')::jsonb
where properties::json->>'url' = 'www.example.com';
```

You can see here [*Demo*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6cd800a4d696abe0bdee366578f2e360)

Answer (score 5):

You should store the records as `JSON` instead of `TEXT` so that type casting won't be required at all places.

If you are running Postgres 9.5+, you could make use of `jsonb_set`

```
UPDATE 
   services SET properties = jsonb_set(properties::jsonb,
                 '{url}' , '"www.mydomain.com"' )::text
WHERE 
   properties::json->>'url' = 'www.example.com';
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5a6a336f942be02d3ccc49fcf220f6df)